# Last textBox inputted value, Settings saving

Tags: c#, textbox, settings

Currently trying to save settings of last inputted  textBox value (e.g. number). 
Partially this is working code. However, that code allows to remember last value while closing/opening of **Parameter_Form**(subForm). In case of closing **MainForm** (application itself), the last textBox value doesn't retain. Why? The history hasn't record. Also I can't get why the cell 'value' is empty. Please see pic.

```
private void Parameter_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {

        Properties.Settings.Default.textBoxLastValue = textBox1.Text;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();


    }
```

[image]

---

I've found following stuff. Please see attached pic.

[image]

Principally it's that number I've inputted in textBox.
There's no issue within app running and opening/closing subForm.
There's an issue after closing of MainForm.

Comment: When you put a breakpoint on `Properties.Settings.Default.textBoxLastValue = textBox1.Text;` and debugged, what did you find?

Comment: Why are you using `System.Char` vs `System.String`?

Answer (score 1):

If you load and save settings manually, you should make sure you load settings in form load event and also save it in form closing event:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.Test;
}
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.Test = textBox1.Text;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

If you are using data binding to settings, then you just need to save when closing.